# Delphi communication with C++ dll (parameters)

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, parameters

Hi I'm having quite some issues with integrating a DLL inside my Delphi 2007 application.

i suspect that I'm doing something wrong with the parameters of the calls.
At this moment i have 2 issues, but i think they are related to eachother.

1)
First call with the DLL:
from the .h file:

```
extern "C" {

__declspec(dllexport) HRESULT Startup(char* version);

}
```

This call should initialize the DLL and give me the version back of the DLL. HRESULT should be 0, and the version pointer should contain the version.

My Delphi code:

```
function Startup(var version: Pchar): HRESULT; cdecl; stdcall; external 'myDLL.dll';
```

And the actual call:

```
var
  res : HRESULT;
  Name1 : PChar;
  test : AnsiString;
  buf2: array [0..20] of AnsiChar;
begin
  FillChar(buf2,20,0);
  Name1:= @buf2[0];
  res := RdmStartup(Name1);
//Here res = 0, but the Name1 stays empty, and the buf2 still contains 0.
end;
```

But as the result is 0 the call was a success.

Then my second issue: i need to call a function in the DLL that will open a COM port.

The .h:

```
extern "C" {
__declspec(dllexport) HRESULT Open(HWND hWnd, int Port, DWORD BaudRate, DWORD Interval); 
}
```

And my Delphi declare:

```
function Open(hWnd: HWND;Port : integer;BaudRate:LongInt;Interval:LongInt): HRESULT; cdecl; stdcall; external 'myDLL.dll';
```

and i call this by:

```
res:= Open(self.Handle,5,115200,500);
```

And here i'm getting a failure back from the DLL in the res variable.
i also have the source of the DLL, and the failure that i'm getting is from the part where the DLL is checking if the parameters are valid, if they are valid it will continue, else return the error i'm currently getting.

The things it is checking:

```
if(hWnd == NULL)
{
    return false;
}
if(BaudRate != 2400 && BaudRate != 9600 && BaudRate != 38400 && BaudRate != 115200)
{
    return false;
} 
if(IntervalTimer < 300)
{
    return false;
}
std::string strPortName = lexical_cast<std::string>( format("COM%d") % Port);
std::string strPortName(lpPortName.c_str());
std::string::size_type loci = strPortName.find("COM");
if( loci == std::string::npos )
{
    return false;
}
return true;
```

And one of these above is returning false on my call, because if the result of this function is false, the DLL gives the error i'm currently getting in the results.
Does anyone have an idea of what i am doing wrong?

i've tried numerous of combinations for the types in the end i sticked to the conversion i found at: http://www.drbob42.com/delphi/headconv.htm
i've also tried different ways of reading the char pointer, but all of them failed.....

So at this stage i know i am succesfully communicating with the DLL as i'm getting different HRESULTs back for the 2 calls, but i suspect my parameters are not working like the should.

I'm using Delphi 2007 and the C++ DLL was build with VS2010.

Comment: You are lucky you put `stdcall` after `cdecl`,  since most functions returning a `HRESULT` are `stdcall`, and in this case, it overrules the `cdecl`. You can remove the `cdecl`, since it is simply a **different** calling convention that is not compatible with `stdcall`.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I always thought that if the DLL was build with other compiler than embarcadero and there is more than one parameter that you had to use cdecl. I guess I was wrong then

Comment: Oh great, i tried all combinations with those as well ;) also if i did not define either of them everything worked like it is working now. but i will remove the cdecl!

Comment: `cdecl` and `stdcall`, hedging your bets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of Startup is pretty suspicious:

```
__declspec(dllexport) HRESULT Startup(char* version);
```

This translates into:

```
function Startup(version: PAnsiChar): HResult; stdcall; external 'myDLL.dll';
```

So there should be no `var` there.

I got from your comments that the `cdecl` calling convention works for some of your code. In that case **remove** `stdcall`, since it overrules the preceding `cdecl`.

The declaration of `Open()` seems to be pretty OK (I would use `DWORD` as type, not `Longint`, especially since `DWORD` is `Longword` these days -- but in Win32 they are the same size, so that won't make any big difference for you). And you seem to be passing the right parameters too.

You did not write what the `HRESULT` value is that you get back. But I assume that the port `COM5` simply cannot be opened with these settings.

#### What can you do?

You should remove the `var` from `Startup()`.

So you can try:

- to use `cdecl` instead of `stdcall` (the `stdcall` in your declaration overrules the `cdecl`)
- to open different COM ports with different parameters
- to decode the `HRESULT` that is returned.

A better diagnosis is not possible, from a distance, without the same hardware and software, sorry.

You could read my [article on conversion](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html). This has also a few paragraphs that explain how to debug the code to find out the proper calling convention. It can probably help you with more of your problems converting headers, too.

Comment: Thanks for the info! i put in the var because i read somewhere that either a var or a out was needed in order to get a return value (can't find it in my enormous history list anymore.) For the DWORD, i also tried those, same results :( The HRESULT i'm getting back is a custom one from the DLL. and it only returns that if the statement from my OP is false. (so either the handle is null, port is not formatted well, baudrate is incorrect or the interval is lower then 300. It does not even try to open a port yet! but i will check your article!

Comment: Nope, header file specifies no calling convention, so the default applies, `cdecl`.

Comment: Wow 1 of the issues just got resolved! the version is now returning! i removed the var, only put in cdecl! no idea how i did not come up with that combination yet..... PChar and PAnsiChar are the same in Delphi2007 so that should not make a difference.

Comment: You use var or out with normal variables, but not with pointers to buffers. You should always strictly convert what the C code tells you. Var changes the order of indirection, so don't use it when converting C pointers, unless you really really know what you are doing. In doubt, use pointers and no var.

Comment: PChar and PAnsiChar are the same in D2007, but not in any later version, so you should get used to specify the correct type. I assume your DLL does not have different Ansi and Wide (suffix A and W) versions of each routine?

Comment: FWIW, for such work, really read th article I mention. I wrote it, and I have been told that it really helped many people already.

Comment: Yeah will read it! it is quite extensive and looks good! will report back if it resolves the issue. i personally suspect i'm doing something wrong with the HWND or the portnumber int. as the DLL is returning a message before it did anything, so it only checked if the dll thinks the params are valid, and found them not valid.....

Comment: ***Check the HRESULT***. The numbers returned are documented all over the web (usually the hex value, but try both).

Comment: The HRESULT is: 0x8000010B, this matches special error code from the DLL. (self made!) and it returns that value if the checking parameters is false, and the check itself i posted in my OP. if i check them with what i send that sould not be possible....

Comment: @Nick It's not fair to ask us to debug your onward code. Rudy addressed that which you raised in the question. Now the task is for you to fix your problems. That said, Rudy got the calling convention wrong. It is `cdecl` in spite of the confusion in the answer. It would have been better for Rudy to have fixed that in an edit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i didnt mean he debug my code, just to point out that the Hresult is not a default result, but a specific one. Though i just found something weird, as soon as i changed the HWND to DWORD the call succeeded. So it seems that there might be a difference in the HWND types of Delphi and C++..... @ Rudy thanks for all the help!

Comment: No. HWND is the same everywhere. But HWND and DWORD are not the same. The former is pointer sized, the latter is 32 bits everywhere. Not that that should make a difference since your pointers are 32 bits.

Comment: Your edit isn't any better. You don't need to guess the calling convention from the code. You have the declaration in the header file.

Comment: @david: No, you don't. What looks like cdecl may be stdcall after all. Various compilers provide options to set the default calling convention.

Comment: Not relevant to library code. It's cdecl. Stop digging.

Comment: @David: of course it can be relevant to library code. It all depends on who wrote the library. What do you mean with "Stop digging"? Digging for what?

Comment: No for library code you supply a header file that you don't expect to be compiled in a particular way. Trying to argue that the function is stdcall as you do is silly. Your answer still makes that claim. Fine. If you won't change it that's up to you.

Comment: Since we don't see the entire header file, and we don't know if there is a `#pragma` of some kind, you can simply not be sure of that. I know from experience that what may look like `cdecl` at first sight doesn't have to be. Only if you see the entire header and the headers it includes, you really know. Note that not all libraries/DLLs are written the correct way either. Some even expose templates and other C++-specific features and don't care if/don't know that the user can't use them if they don't use a particular version of a specific C++ compiler.