# Calling dll with *char, use PAnsiChar or AnsiString in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, dllimport

When having a dll written in C with the following function declaration:

```
WORD StartDownloadTo(char * pFileName);
```

With Delphi 10.4, should I convert it to:

```
function StartDownloadTo(FileName: AnsiString): Word cdecl stdcall;
```

this can be called with:

```
var
  filename: string;
begin
  StartDownloadTo(AnsiString(FileName));
end;
```

or

```
function StartDownloadTo(FileName: PAnsiChar): Word cdecl stdcall;
```

which can be called with:

```
var
  filename: string;
begin
  StartDownloadTo(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(fileName)));
end;
```

Both seems to work. Is one better than the other for a reason that I do not know?

Comment: Since the `StrPas` function is deprecated (I believe with Delphi XE7) you can use both variants. I still prefer the second one with PAnsiChar because the translation between C and Object Pascal is clearer to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your declarations is correct.

The correct declaration is:

```
function StartDownloadTo(FileName: PAnsiChar): Word; cdecl;
```

You had a mixup in the calling convention.

Whilst using `AnsiString` may appear to work, that's really just a coincidence. It just so happens that an `AnsiString` variable points to the first character of the string. To be semantically correct you should use `PAnsiChar`.

Furthermore, in case your string is empty, you need to pass a pointer to a null-terminating character, which is how an empty string is represented as a C string. But if you declare the argument as `AnsiString`, then an empty string leads to a `nil` being passed. If you use `PAnsiChar`, then the `PAnsiChar` cast in the calling code results in the desired handling for empty strings.

Do be aware however, that your use of 8 bit text will not be able to support any characters outside the current user's locale. I would expect to see the C code accepting `const wchar_t *pFileName` and your Delphi code using `PWideChar`.

Comment: Regarding the mixup: I was actually surprised to learn that the compiler accepts two calling conventions. In fact, I can even use them all: `procedure p; register pascal cdecl stdcall safecall;` And I can omit the semicolon. Is this documented behaviour? What does it mean?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, the AnsiString vs PAnsiChar starts to make sense now.

Also thanks for pointing out the calling convention issue, it seems I have to study that a bit. I believe, however, that the file was automatically generated by a tool converting a C .h file to .pas, so I'm a bit puzzled that that part is erroneous.

I am aware of the potential loss of information, however it's necessary when I have to interface to a .dll I don't control, and since it's a filename I need to assume it's not going to be a disaster in this case.

Comment: Andreas Rejbrand: It seems that only the last one is being used, and the others are discarded according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471902/delphi-communication-with-c-dll-parameters#comment66263420_39471902 My experimentation also shows that cdecl is ignored, and if I remove stdcall and leave cdecl everything falls apart (for now obvious reasons).

Comment: `I would expect to see the C code accepting const wchar_t *pFileName`  Why?  Maybe it's something writing to a FAT16 filesystem?  Or writing a file to a path on an 8-bit micro controller?  I don't think we can say what's correct without knowing something about the implementation.

Comment: "*Do be aware however, that your use of 8 bit text will not be able to support any characters outside the current user's locale*" - unless the DLL accepts UTF-8, which will work fine in a `char*` string in C: `StartDownloadTo(PAnsiChar(UTF8String(fileName)));`